# How do you remove the build configuration from .Net Core Library prooject output paths?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I am adding a new .Net 5.0 library project to a solution with several older .Net Framework library projects already present.  All of the existing projects build to a common directory above the root directory of the project.  Specifically, our CommonLibraries.sln builds all of the project outputs to a References directory structured like below:

-Common
--CommonLibraries.sln
-References
--<various .dll files output from the projects inside CommonLibraries.sln>
-<other solutions that reference the .dll files in the References folder>

However, I cannot figure out how to get the .Net 5.0 project to stop building to References/Debug instead of just References.  I've already added:

```
<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
<AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
```

to get rid of the other extraneous bits that you can't modify from the UI, but I can't find any information on removing the Debug or Release level from the output path.

Answer (score 4):

You probably set just BaseOutputPath configuration property. If this is the case, MSBUILD appends $(Configuration) value to it as a subfolder.
If you want to override this policy you have to set OutputPath configuration property instead of (or in addition to) BaseOutputPath, for example:

```
<OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\bin\</OutputPath>
```

Comment: It's critical to remember the trailing backslash here, otherwise you'll still get the Configuration property added to the path (VS2022)